# How to do Hierarchical Heteroskedastic Sparse GPs in GPflow?

Tags: gpflow

Is is possible to model a general trend from a population using GPflow and also have individual predictions, as in [Hensman et al](https://bmcbioinformatics.biomedcentral.com/articles/10.1186/1471-2105-14-252)?

Specifically, I am trying to fit spatial data from a bunch of individuals from a clinical assessment. For each individual, am I dealing with approx 20000 datapoints (different number of recordings for each individual), which definitely restricts myself to a sparse implementation. In addition to this, there also seemes that I need an input dependent noise model, hence the heteroskedasticity.

I have fitted a hetero-sparse model as in [this notebook example](https://gpflow.github.io/GPflow/develop/notebooks/advanced/heteroskedastic.html), but I am not sure how to scale it to perform the hierarchical learning. Any ideas would be welcome :)

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/mattramos/SparseHGP may be helpful. This repo is gives GPFlow2 code for modelling a sparse hierarchical model. Note, there are still some rough edges in the implementation that require an expensive for loop to be constructed.